# ActionController::RoutingError Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am encountering a weird little error when I start up the server and navigate to my apps root page.

```
Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2017-04-27 03:01:32 -0600
Processing by AicoController#home as HTML
  Rendering aico/home.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered aico/home.html.erb within layouts/application (187.7ms)
  Rendered application/_favicon.html.erb (7.5ms)
  Rendered nav/_signed_out.html.erb (2.5ms)
  Rendered footer/_footer.html.erb (1.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 304ms (Views: 294.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/..." for ::1 at 2017-04-27 03:01:32 -0600

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/..."):
```

It renders the page and doesn't pop a better errors error, but in production, it is not letting the page load at all.

I have never encountered this before, I'll place my routes file below and the full stack trace too. Any assistance here will be greatly appreciated as I have no idea what I'm looking at (and restarting the server didn't fix the problem)

The only time this error occurs is when I navigate to my root page.

> **My Routes File:**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'aico#home'

  get 'aico/fire'
  get 'aico/water'
  get 'aico/mold'
  get 'aico/asbestos'
  get 'aico/biohazard'
  get 'aico/elemental'
  get 'aico/general_contracting'
  get 'aico/roofing_exterior'
  get 'aico/about'
  get 'aico/grow_op'

  get 'contact-me', to: 'messages#new', as: 'new_message'
  post 'contact-me', to: 'messages#create', as: 'create_message'
end
```

> **Rake Routes Output:**

```
root GET  /                                   aico#home
                   aico_fire GET  /aico/fire(.:format)                aico#fire
                  aico_water GET  /aico/water(.:format)               aico#water
                   aico_mold GET  /aico/mold(.:format)                aico#mold
               aico_asbestos GET  /aico/asbestos(.:format)            aico#asbestos
              aico_biohazard GET  /aico/biohazard(.:format)           aico#biohazard
              aico_elemental GET  /aico/elemental(.:format)           aico#elemental
    aico_general_contracting GET  /aico/general_contracting(.:format) aico#general_contracting
       aico_roofing_exterior GET  /aico/roofing_exterior(.:format)    aico#roofing_exterior
                  aico_about GET  /aico/about(.:format)               aico#about
                aico_grow_op GET  /aico/grow_op(.:format)             aico#grow_op
                 new_message GET  /contact-me(.:format)               messages#new
              create_message POST /contact-me(.:format)               messages#create
```

> **Full Stack Trace:**

```
Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2017-04-27 03:01:32 -0600
Processing by AicoController#home as HTML
  Rendering aico/home.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered aico/home.html.erb within layouts/application (187.7ms)
  Rendered application/_favicon.html.erb (7.5ms)
  Rendered nav/_signed_out.html.erb (2.5ms)
  Rendered footer/_footer.html.erb (1.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 304ms (Views: 294.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/..." for ::1 at 2017-04-27 03:01:32 -0600

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/..."):

actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:53:in `call'
web-console (3.5.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
web-console (3.5.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (3.5.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
web-console (3.5.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
railties (5.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
railties (5.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
railties (5.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
railties (5.0.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
puma (3.8.2) lib/puma/configuration.rb:224:in `call'
puma (3.8.2) lib/puma/server.rb:600:in `handle_request'
puma (3.8.2) lib/puma/server.rb:435:in `process_client'
puma (3.8.2) lib/puma/server.rb:299:in `block in run'
puma (3.8.2) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
  Rendering /Users/taurenltd/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.html.erb within rescues/layout
  Rendering /Users/taurenltd/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb
  Rendered /Users/taurenltd/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered collection of /Users/taurenltd/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_route.html.erb [13 times] (4.5ms)
  Rendered /Users/taurenltd/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_table.html.erb (7.3ms)
  Rendering /Users/taurenltd/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
  Rendered /Users/taurenltd/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.2ms)
  Rendered /Users/taurenltd/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (95.4ms)
```

Please let me know if I require any further info, I could just be overlooking something small, any assistance here would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers.

Comment: You must have a link or call to "..." somewhere on your homepage. Search your codebase for it.

Comment: try  `root to: 'aico#home', via: 'get'`

Comment: Also, does the view 'home' exist?

Comment: yes the home view exists, i tried the route above, same error, im picking through code right now trying to see if i have a / somewhere that messing with me but no avail so far.

Comment: Could it be that you are developing on windows and deploying on linux? Might be whitespace or utf-8 issue.

Comment: no im developing on a Mac, deploying via ssh and cap to digital ocean droplet

Comment: File encoding is utf-8 throughout?

Comment: yeah, i actually just found the culprit!

Comment: it was a series of ... that came with the bootstrap 4 carousel that i hadnt converted into rails code as of yet. replaced with a # and it workes like a top now

Comment: That was my next question, Started GET "/..." the three dots look strange and does not match root in any sense :-)

Comment: funny how something so trivial can blow up an app like that lol. thanks again